# How do I get both Ubuntu Server after I installed Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: server, partitioning

I want to partition my hard drive so I can switch back and forth, but I can't find anywhere where it tells me how. I have a 1TB hard drive so I definitely have space, and I want to experiment with the server. Does anyone have any instructions on how to walk me through partitioning and installing correctly?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The Ubuntu server partitioning UI is not that unintuitive. Try it and tell us if you get stuck.

Comment: So I can boot up from the server cd and partiton it from there?

Comment: Of course. It is not the normal GUI of the live CD, but you don't have to manually enter commands either, it's a TUI. It would help if you already have free space or a partition you intend to overwrite, but it can do anything the GUI can.

Comment: @user300203, you can boot using live cd, use gparted to resize/create partitions you need then try install Ubuntu server

Comment: Alright, so I'm on gparted and I shrunk my original partition. But it then asks what kind of filesystem I want. Also is this a primary or extended partition? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @user300203, you can create only 4 primary partitions, so if you planning for <=4  then make primary. If you want more, then make 3 primary and 1 extended(then logical partition inside as much as you want). remember that grub boot can be installed only in primary partitions (no logical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have both of them.

Ubuntu Server is not something completely different from Ubuntu Desktop. But usually server setup does not have GUI, and that's all. Any package you install comes from one centralized repository.

The installer looks different (no GUI, as I've already mentioned), but right now, if you already have Ubuntu installed, I don't see any reason to install a separate Ubuntu Server instance.